# View outlets are nil on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, xib

My files owner has 3 outlets, and all of them are nil on viewDidLoad...

```
__weak IBOutlet UIView *mainImagePlaceholderView;
__weak IBOutlet UILabel *mainImageLabel;
__weak IBOutlet UIView *imageFilmstripPlaceholderView;
```

These are located in my .m file, ...

```
@implementation iRpImageViewerViewController
{
    ...
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *mainImagePlaceholderView;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *mainImageLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UIView *imageFilmstripPlaceholderView;
    ...
}
```

- My class in question is iRpImageViewerViewController.xib
- In IB, the 'files owner custom class' is 'iRpImageViewerViewController.m'
- In IB, the nib 'view custom class' is UIView

Everything shows as hooked up properly.
I have cleaned my build folder.
I have cleared my derived data folder.
I even tried to trick the views into loading by referring to them in the init method and setting their backcolor.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        theMainImageGridviewControl = [[IGGridView alloc]initWithFrame:mainImagePlaceholderView.frame style:IGGridViewStyleSingleCellPaging];

        // Set additional properties to configure the grid view
        theMainImageGridviewControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        theMainImageGridviewControl.selectionType = IGGridViewSelectionTypeCell;
        theMainImageGridviewControl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        theMainImageGridviewControl.allowHorizontalBounce = NO;
        theMainImageGridviewControl.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
        theMainImageGridviewControl.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;

        [mainImagePlaceholderView addSubview:theMainImageGridviewControl];

        // Setting a breakpoint here reveals that all the outlets are nil
        [self addAChildViewController:theFilmstripViewController toViewWithTag:imageFilmstripPlaceholderView.tag];

        [self constructAndConfigurePrimaryImageMarker];

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are defining these outlets?
Have you tried `@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *name` to define in your .h file ?

Comment: They aren't in my .h file, they are inside my .m file, just beneath the @implementation SomeClass inside the brackets { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you created the XIB and the view controller, but did you try adding the following to the initializer that you calling for the view controller:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"iRpImageViewerViewController" bundle:nil];
```